# Is there some kind of parameter in ado.net entity model that crashes the toList() function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using the ado.net entity model to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database.  I use Linq-to-Entities to copy the data to a list, where I do some other stuff with it.  The entity model was built by importing a view from the database.  Anyway, I wrote the linq query, and it does in fact return all 23 unique rows.  Unfortunately, however, if it comes across some data and it doesn't know what to do with (i.e., if there's a pound sign or an ampersand in a string), it returns objects from elsewhere in the data.  Most of the time, it happens with strings that have unusual characters in it (ampersands and pound signs), but it does it for just an ordinary string as well.  Does anybody have any thoughts?

```
   IQueryable<LenGIS_PlanningSUPvw> supQuery = from sup in accelaContext.LenGIS_PlanningSUPvw where sup.SUPClass == selectType select sup;
    List<LenGIS_PlanningSUPvw> theList = supQuery.ToList<LenGIS_PlanningSUPvw>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= theList.Count - 1; i++) {
        LenGIS_PlanningSUPvw sup = theList.ElementAt(i);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"the project name: " + sup.ProjectName.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"the project id: " + sup.ProjectID.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"the index in the list: " + i.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"*********************"); 
    }
```

gives output that looks like this:

```
the project name: proj1
the project id: SU93-06-PERM
the index in the list: 0
____________________________
the project name: proj2
the project id: SU97-09-PERM
the index in the list: 1
____________________________
the project name: proj1
the project id: SU93-06-PERM
the index in the list: 2
____________________________
the project name: proj3
the project id: SU04-13
the index in the list: 3
____________________________
the project name: proj4
the project id: SU04-19
the index in the list: 4
____________________________
the project name: proj3
the project id: SU04-13
the index in the list: 5
____________________________
the project name: proj3
the project id: SU04-13
the index in the list: 6
____________________________
```

when in fact, the project name and id should be (and in the SQL Server database, is) unique.

Also, I just tested, and it does it from the IQueryable, too (that is, it doesn't matter if you're using .toList<>() or not).

One more thing: it doesn't screw up if you use traditional ado.net to query and return data.

Comment: Have you checked the executed query in SQL Server Profiler? What results do you get? Are you sure it's a problem with ORM?

Comment: I checked with standard ado.net and it returned what I expected it to.